# Issue scanning barcode in java swing

Tags: java, swing, barcode

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 *   Listens for bar code input and puts it into a String Buffer.
 *
 */
public class BarcodeReader {

    private static final long THRESHOLD = 120;
    private static final int MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH = 8;

    public interface BarcodeListener 
    {
        void onBarcodeRead(String barcode);
    }

    private final StringBuffer barcode = new StringBuffer();
    private static final List<BarcodeListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<BarcodeListener>();
    private long lastEventTimeStamp = 0L;

    public BarcodeReader() {

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    if (e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (e.getWhen() - lastEventTimeStamp > THRESHOLD) {
                        barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                    }

                    lastEventTimeStamp = e.getWhen();

                     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                     {
                         if (barcode.length() >= MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH) 
                             fireBarcode(barcode.toString());

                         barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                     } 
                     else 
                         barcode.append(e.getKeyChar());

                    return false;
                } 
                catch (UnsupportedOperationException err) 
                {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

            }
        });

    }

    protected void fireBarcode(String barcode) {
        for (BarcodeListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.onBarcodeRead(barcode);
        }
    }

    public void addBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

And the implementing code is as below:

```
private void startReading() 
    {
       BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

       reader.addBarcodeListener(new BarcodeListener() {

            public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
                System.out.println(barcode);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now the issue with this code is when i scan the barcode its returning me multiple lines of the same data. Thus i couldnot figure out what is happening. Help needed desperately.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should explain which library reads barcode, or if it is an image, a pdf , etc ...  etc ...
For my experience reading barcodes is not too simple, but one of my oldest implementations worked analyzing a jpeg image.
You have to imagine to cut the barcode with a line passing through all the black bar code lines. The code is identified by the distance between the intersections. So if you pass multiple lines on the same bar code, you will have multiple ( and same ) results.
A lot of libraries do a work like this, so to prevent multiple lines you have to recognize a pattern in your bar code that makes you understand thet you've found the code. Forgive me for my horrible english !

Comment: Thank you @Homo Filmens for your answer but i'm trying to implement using a keyboard hook.